# Rails route resources with multiple params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've just setup my router to route category resources with `:id` and `:alias`:

```
resources :categories, param: 'id/:alias'
```

Now, my routes are setup correctly, for example 'show' becomes:

```
category GET    /categories/:id/:alias(.:format)     categories#show
```

The `to_param` method on `Category`:

```
def to_param
  { id: id, alias: name.parameterize }
end
```

When using `link_to category`, it throws this error:

- No route matches {:controller=>"categories", :action=>"show", :id=>#< Category id: 2, name: "Buiten", description: "", ancestry: nil, created_at: "2014-04-25 16:13:11", updated_at: "2014-04-25 16:13:11">, :alias=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:alias]

I want to use links like this:

```
= link_to category
```

I do NOT want to use links like this:

```
= link_to category_path( { id: category.id, alias: category.name.parameterize } )
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what it is showing in rails console `app.category_path(id: 2, alias: "asas")` did it throw error ?

Comment: your alias is `nil` that's why it was throwing error

Comment: you can verify my comment  `app.category_path(id: 2, alias: nil)` now you see it will throw error

Comment: look at your post `:alias=>nil, :format=>nil}`

Comment: you can simply avoid alias in `to_param` and send it as a parameter of query like `/categories/2?alias=anything`

Comment: I want my linking to be simple, like `link_to category`, is this possible?

Comment: yes `link_to category, category_path(2, "asa")` and

Answer (score 0):

you can simply solve the alias nil in this way

```
  def to_param
    "#{self.id}-#{self.alias}"
  end
```

Comment: Still the same error.. It seems to me that we cannot return a hash from `to_param`